# Tiny plot output from sankeyNetwork (NetworkD3) in Firefox

Tags: r, shiny, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

As per object, I get a very small plot in Firefox when using `sankeyNetwork()` from [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) in [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) but not in Chrome or RStudio.

I have not included any CSS or JS in the script - the code below produces this result for me.

Is there any CSS property I have missed?

I am using R 3.4.1, shiny 1.1.0, networkD3 0.4 and Firefox 52.9.0.

Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(networkD3)

labels = as.character(1:9)
ui <- tagList(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "appName"
    ),
    ##### dasboardSidebar #####
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        id = "sidebar",
        menuItem("plots",
                 tabName = "sPlots")
      )
    ),
    ##### dashboardBody #####
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        ##### tab #####
        tabItem(
          tabName = "sPlots",
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel(
              "Sankey plot",
              fluidRow(
                box(title = "title",
                    solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, status = "primary",
                    sankeyNetworkOutput("sankeyHSM1")
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  HSM = matrix(rep(c(10000, 700, 10000-700, 200, 500, 50, 20, 10, 2,40,10,10,10,10),4),ncol = 4)
  sankeyHSMNetworkFun = function(x,ndx) {
    nodes = data.frame("name" = factor(labels, levels = labels),
                       "group" = as.character(c(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4)))
    links = as.data.frame(matrix(byrow=T,ncol=3,c(
      0, 1, NA,
      0, 2, NA,
      1, 3, NA,
      1, 4, NA,
      3, 5, NA,
      3, 6, NA,
      3, 7, NA,
      3, 8, NA
    )))
    links[,3] = HSM[2:(nrow(links)+1),] %>% {rowSums(.[,(ndx-1)*2+c(1,2)])}
    names(links) = c("source","target","value")
    sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",NodeGroup = "group",
                  fontSize=12,sinksRight = FALSE)
  }
  output$sankeyHSM1 = renderSankeyNetwork({
    sankeyHSMNetworkFun(values$HSM,1)
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

------------------ EDIT --------------------

Thanks to @CJYetman for indicating `onRender()` as a possible solution - however this fails when there are two plots generated side by side as in the MRE below (note in addition to the second sankey plot I have also added javascript code to re-draw the figures when the window size changes as the plot does not appear to do it automatically).

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

labels = as.character(1:9)
ui <- tagList(
  tags$head(
    tags$script('
var dimension = [0, 0];
$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
    dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
    dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
    Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
});
$(window).resize(function(e) {
    dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
    dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
    Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
});
                            ')
  ),
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "appName"
    ),
    ##### dasboardSidebar #####
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        id = "sidebar",
        menuItem("plots",
                 tabName = "sPlots")
      )
    ),
    ##### dashboardBody #####
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        ##### tab #####
        tabItem(
          tabName = "sPlots",
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel(
              "Sankey plot",
              fluidRow(
                box(title = "title",
                    solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, status = "primary",
                    sankeyNetworkOutput("sankeyHSM1")
                ),
                box(title = "plot2",
                    solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, status = "primary",
                    sankeyNetworkOutput("sankeyHSM2"))
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  HSM = matrix(rep(c(10000, 700, 10000-700, 200, 500, 50, 20, 10, 2,40,10,10,10,10),4),ncol = 4)
  sankeyHSMNetworkFun = function(x,ndx) {
    nodes = data.frame("name" = factor(labels, levels = labels),
                       "group" = as.character(c(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4)))
    links = as.data.frame(matrix(byrow=T,ncol=3,c(
      0, 1, NA,
      0, 2, NA,
      1, 3, NA,
      1, 4, NA,
      3, 5, NA,
      3, 6, NA,
      3, 7, NA,
      3, 8, NA
    )))
    links[,3] = HSM[2:(nrow(links)+1),] %>% {rowSums(.[,(ndx-1)*2+c(1,2)])}
    names(links) = c("source","target","value")
    sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",NodeGroup = "group",
                  fontSize=12,sinksRight = FALSE)
  }
  output$sankeyHSM1 = renderSankeyNetwork({
    req(input$dimension)
    sankeyHSMNetworkFun(values$HSM,1) %>%
      onRender('document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].setAttribute("viewBox", "")')
  })
  output$sankeyHSM2 = renderSankeyNetwork({
    req(input$dimension)
    sankeyHSMNetworkFun(values$HSM,2) %>%
      onRender('document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].setAttribute("viewBox", "")')
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

------------------ EDIT2 --------------------

Second problem above solved - either by referring to the second svg item on the page as per @CJYetman's comment below using `document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[1].setAttribute("viewBox","")`, or by going into the objects themselves selecting their first svg element with `document.getElementById("sankeyHSM2").getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].setAttribute("viewBox","")`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be the result of Firefox reacting to the `viewbox` svg property differently than other browsers. It might be worthwhile to submit this as an issue here https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues

In the meantime, you could work around this by resetting the `viewbox` attribute using some JavaScript and `htmlwidgets::onRender()`. Here's an example using a minimized version of your example. (Resetting the `viewbox` attribute may have other consequences)

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(networkD3)
library(magrittr)

nodes = data.frame("name" = factor(as.character(1:9)),
                   "group" = as.character(c(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4)))

links = as.data.frame(matrix(byrow = T, ncol = 3, c(
  0, 1, 1400,
  0, 2, 18600,
  1, 3, 400,
  1, 4, 1000,
  3, 5, 100,
  3, 6, 40,
  3, 7, 20,
  3, 8, 4
)))
names(links) = c("source","target","value")

sn <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source", 
                    Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
                    NodeGroup = "group", fontSize = 12, sinksRight = FALSE)

htmlwidgets::onRender(sn, 'document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].setAttribute("viewBox", "")')
```

---

UPDATE (2019.10.26)

This is probably a safer implementation of removing the viewBox...

```r
htmlwidgets::onRender(sn, 'function(el) { el.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].removeAttribute("viewBox") }')
```

---

UPDATE 2020.04.02

My currently preferred method to do this is to use `htmlwidgets::onRender` to target specifically the SVG contained by the passed htmlwidget, like this...

```r
onRender(sn, 'function(el) { el.querySelector("svg").removeAttribute("viewBox") }')
```

That can then be done specifically to as many `htmlwidgets` on your page as necessary, for instance...

```r
onRender(sn, 'function(el) { el.querySelector("svg").removeAttribute("viewBox") }')

onRender(sn2, 'function(el) { el.querySelector("svg").removeAttribute("viewBox") }')
```

Comment: Thanks @CJYetman - this works very well when there is a single chart on the page but fails when there are two, any ideas? I am editing the question above with an MRE

Comment: Change the `[0]` to `[1]` in the line of JavaScript to select the second svg. Duplicate the entire JacaScript line and set the numbers appropriately to affect multiple svgs (use a `;` between JavaScript commands)

Comment: I have _just_ managed to solve this by using `document.getElementById().getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].setAttribute()` which worked like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: Am trying @CJ Yetman solution within blogdown but it doesn't work in my case :(

Comment: Thanks @CJYetman for pointing out this solution. In ```rmarkdown``` this also works nicely as final line of a custom function to create multiple sankey plots from a list of dfs using ```lapply```. For example ```list_sn <- lapply (list_dfs, function(x) {'functional arguments defining sn ending with:'  onRender(sn, 'function(el) { el.querySelector("svg").removeAttribute("viewBox") }')})``` and subsequent output using ```list_sn[[i]]```.